# Text Processing - Get 2 lines with exact text between them

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have file with unknown number of blocks of text consisting of starting keyword "Start", ending keyword "End" and optional text between them with one exact keyword "Disk" on every line and I need to get rid of the ones where there is nothing between them, see the example.

I am processing input like this:

```
Server1:Start
Server1:End
Server2:Start
Disk1
Disk2
Server2:End
Server3:Start
Disk1
Server3:End
```

, and my desired output is this:

```
Server2:Start
Disk1
Disk2
Server2:End
Server3:Start
Disk1
Server3:End
```

I know, that I can use 'awk' or 'sed' to find text between 2 lines, but I do not know what to do, if there are multiple occurrences of these 2 lines or if there is no text between these 2 lines.

I am running Ubuntu 17.10.

Looking forward to any help.

edit: I deleted the post first time, because I thought that I can do it using `sed -e '/Start/,/End/d'`, but this actually removes everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete back-to-back `Start` and `End` lines, this should do in GNU sed:

```
$ sed -e '/Start/ {N; /^\(.*\):Start\n\1:End$/d }' < input
```

if we see `Start`, load the next line with `N`, then see if the contents of the buffer are just `Somename:Start\nSomename:End` with `Somename` same on both lines (`\n` is a newline). If so, delete it. Here, `\1` is a reference to the first group within `\(..\)`, and matches the same string that was encountered there. `.*` just means any number (`*`) of any characters (`.`).

Using `sed -e '/Start/,/End/d'` would indeed delete every single line, since the range matches all lines between the starting and ending patterns. Everything in the input is between `Start` and `End`, so everything is deleted.

Comment: Actually it isn't literally "Server2" and "Server3". There are actual unknown URLs and the file is much longer than that. Pardon me for not specifying this part.

Comment: @mikro45, argh, no, pardon me for missing the sentence with the actual point of the question.

Comment: It isn't working for whole file the way, you wrote it. But when I changed it to `sed -e '/Start/ {N; /^\(.*\):Start\n\(.*\):End$/d }' < input`, changing "\1" for "\(.*\)", it works now. 
Can you explain what do "\1" and "\(.*\)" do?

Comment: @mikro45, yeah, I assumed the label would repeat identically, as it seemed to be in the example. That was mostly to avoid the possibility that the pattern would match something else, if `:End` could appear on some other line. `/^.*:Start\n.*:End$/` would relax that, and just match any strings before `:Start` and `:End`. (Without the `\1`, the `\(` and `\)` are also unnecessary since they only act as a place for the `\1` to point to.)

Answer (score 1):

another solution, as I like trying to do these in awk.

```
BEGIN { 
    RS="End\n"
    ORS="End\n"
} 
NF > 2
```

using the built in `RS` or record separator variable, awk will treat between each `End\n` as a record, and presuming that the `servername:Start` and `servername:End` are both single words, its just a case of printing the lines with more that 2 fields via the `NF > 2` line. If this is true, the whole line will be printed, with `End\n` used as the output record separator (`ORS`)

```
~$>echo '
Server1:Start
Server1:End
Server2:Start
Disk1
Disk2
Server2:End
Server3:Start
Disk1
Server3:End
' | awk 'BEGIN { RS="End\n"; ORS="End\n"; } NF > 2;'
Server2:Start
Disk1
Disk2
Server2:End
Server3:Start
Disk1
Server3:End
```